# Receive keyboard input from within docker in detached mode

Tags: docker, input, keyboard

I'm wondering whether there is any possibility to receive all keyboard input from the docker host while running the docker image in detached mode.

To explain this question in more detail, let's assume I've got an application that does not do anything else than just writing any keyboard input that it receives to a text file.
Additionally, let's assume this application is running within a docker container.

When I start this docker container by running

`docker run -it --name mykeylogger mykeylogger`

any keystroke that I make is successfully written to the file.

However, I need to run this docker container in detached mode (-d), i.e.

`docker run -d -it --name mykeylogger mykeylogger`

Unfortunately, also after searching quite a long time on the internet, I don't find a solution to tell the container to still forward any keystroke made on the host to the application running in the Docker container.

Thus do you maybe have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.